# CR is not showing same as I designed in Designed in Designer Mode in VS 2013 and CR 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

In "Main Report Preview" section the report is showing properly as I have designed but when I load the CR from the .exe file, then it is not showing as I designed. I am using C#.Net and SQL with CR 2013.

Rebuild many time but useless.
[image: Crystal Report Preview]

Comment: Do you have different version of the CR Engine in your designer versus your executable?  For example, I design reports in Crystal Reports 2016, but the software where reports are executed was built around Crystal Reports 2011.  Because of the difference in CR Engine version, design features that are supported in the 2016 version will not work for reports when they are executed by the software that uses the 2011 version because those features were not supported in the 2011 version.  Vertical alignment is a good example of one such design feature.

Comment: CR are same version... @R.McMillan